# git push rejected

Tags: git, push

I give up!
Whenever I try to push I get a stupid:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:companyX/projectX.git'
```

Our team has a new git setup. Instead of making private branches I now Forked our main repository (on github) to create my own copy.

At some point what I did was:

```
$ git fetch upstream master:upstreammaster
```

So here is my current setup::

```
$ git branch
master
* upstreammaster

$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:userX/projectX.git
upstream    git@github.com:companyX/projectX.git
```

where userX is my private repository.

So I go and make some changes to my upstreammaster branch, and the PULL from "upstream master".
Everything merges and stuff:

```
$ git pull upstream master
remote: Counting objects: 95, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
remote: Total 60 (delta 54), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (60/60), done.
From git@github.com:companyX/projectX
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by recursive.
stuff                      |  165 ++++++++++++--------
stuff                      |   35 ++--
stuff                       |  107 ++++++++++---
stuff                       |  105 ++++++++++---
stuff             |   24 ++--
stuff               |    9 +-
stuff                   |   53 +++----
stuff            |   44 +++---
stuff              |   52 +++----
stuff |   32 +----
stuff          |    4 +-
 stuff             |  138 ++++++++---------
stuff     |   58 ++++----
stuff    |  115 ++++++++------
stuff          |    5 +-
stuff                       |   39 ++---
stuff                        |   28 ++--
 17 files changed, 560 insertions(+), 453 deletions(-)
```

but then when I try to do:

```
$ git push upstream master
To git@github.com:companyX/projectX.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:companyX/projectX.git'
```

Any help would be greately appreciated! If you need clarification please ask, I will reply!

Comment: @drozzy: Do you know why Git does not accept your command? Your command once worked for me. After I moved Git to another folder in my Mac, I get a similar error message.

Comment: no sorry i don't know. Right now I mostly do "git push upstream master", after having merged my other branch into upstreammaster.

Comment: See also [Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/whats-a-fast-forward-in-git).

Comment: Check your folder permissions on the git-servers repo folder for write-access (also for subdirectories!)

Comment: git push can be rejected if you have two branches with similar name, in my case my second branch was named: branch1.name()+ '/specification'. Git rejected it and i solved my problem thanks to @Pat Notz

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When doing a push, try specifying the refspec for the upstream master:

```
git push upstream upstreammaster:master
```

Comment: @Jarret: It does not work for me. My code $git push git@github.com:user/repo.git git@github.com:user/repo.git:master.

Comment: Masi, try without using the full URL on the second parameter: git push it@github.com:user/repo.git master

Comment: how to do this on zend studio?

Answer (score 20):

Jarret Hardie is correct.  Or, first merge your changes back into master and then try the push.  By default, `git push` pushes all branches that have names that match on the remote -- and no others.  So those are your two choices -- either specify it explicitly like Jarret said or merge back to a common branch and then push.

There's been talk about this on the Git mail list and it's clear that this behavior is not about to change anytime soon -- many developers rely on this behavior in their workflows.

**Edit/Clarification**

Assuming your `upstreammaster` branch is ready to push then you could do this:

1. Pull in any changes from the upstream.

   $ git pull upstream master
2. Switch to my local master branch

   $ git checkout master
3. Merge changes in from `upstreammaster`

   $ git merge upstreammaster
4. Push my changes up

   $ git push upstream

Another thing that you *may* want to do before pushing is to `rebase` your changes against upstream/master so that your commits are all together.  You can either do that as a separate step between #1 and #2 above (`git rebase upstream/master`) or you can do it as part of your pull (`git pull --rebase upstream master`)

Comment: How do you mean "merge back to a common branch and then push"?
Which is the common branch in this case?

Comment: I had the same problem after checking out and working on a branch, and pushing changes that included an update to a file that had been deleted in the master branch (which I had not touched at all). Another developer tried some Git commands I didn't catch, but the problem remained: `git status` showed that my branch was clean, `git pull` did nothing, but the command `git push` still output `error: failed to push some refs...`.  I finally got the problem fixed like this: 1. `git checkout master`, 2. `git pull`, and 3. `git checkout the_branch_name`.

Comment: er... well, and what happens when you do the first command (git pull upstream master) and you have a conflict in the pull??? You have to solve the conflict before going on??

Answer (score 14):

First use

```
git pull https://github.com/username/repository master
```

and then try

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 13):

First, attempt to pull from the same refspec that you are trying to push to.

If this does not work, you can force a `git push` by using `git push -f <repo> <refspec>`, but use caution: this method can cause references to be deleted on the remote repository.

Answer (score 11):

Actually I got the same error but the below comment worked for me

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Be aware that this solution will remove commits (possibly including work accomplished) in the target branch.

Answer (score 3):

Is your repository at "upstream" a bare repository? I got the same error, but when I change to bare they no longer happen.

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what was causing my problem, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If nothing works, try:

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories <repo> <branch>
```

then do:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

If push request is shows Rejected, then try first pull from your github account and then try push.

Ex:

In my case it was giving an error-

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ashif8984/git-github.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

****So what I did was-****

```
$ git pull
$ git push
```

And the code was pushed successfully into my Github Account.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague had the additional error: `Ask a project Owner or Maintainer to create a default branch`

It turned out he didn't have enough permissions in the git repo (Gitlab). He was able to push when his access level was upgraded.